# Excel - dynamic reference to worksheets

Tags: excel

```
------------

id | formula

------------
1  | =sum('Worksheet 1'!A:A)

2  | =sum('Worksheet 2'!A:A)

3  | =sum('Worksheet 3'!A:A)

------------
```

i want to write a formula that will refer to a different worksheet based on the id.

how to make the numbers 1 and 2 change according to the id of the row it is in instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: Are you writing a VBA Macro, or asking how to use Excel formula auto-fill? If so, please move this question to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `b2`, write

`=SUM(indirect("'Worksheet "& A2 & "'!A:A"))`

Comment: That range reference will fail without wrapping `'` marking the worksheet(s) with spaces in the names.

Comment: Ya, due to the space.  Thanks, @Jeeped .

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate a string that looks like a worksheet range reference you end up with a string that looks like a worksheet range reference. Use INDIRECT to convert to a usable worksheet range reference.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'worksheet "&ROW(1:1)&"'!A:A"))
```